# Passing stack allocated value by reference to a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

I'm working with an external library and there's some code that gives me pause. Basically, there's a vector that is allocated inside a loop (on the stack). That vector is then passed by reference to the constructor of some object, and used to initialize one of the object's vector fields, which was not declared as a reference. Is the newly created object holding a reference to something that no longer exists? Or is this just a more efficient way of copying the vector, in which case the fact that it was allocated on the stack makes no difference?

Here's a minimal example:

```
class Holder {
public:
    Holder(vector<int>& vref) : vec(vref) {}
    vector<int> vec;
}

Holder* MakeHolder() {
    vector<int> v {1, 2};
    return new Holder(v);
}

int main() {
    Holder *h = MakeHolder();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reference held to a departed object, but I certainly wouldn't call it "efficient". Without an `std::move` in that *ctor-initialiser*, the vector must be copied.

You could put `std::move` in there but then `Holder` would be a little confusing to use.

Personally I'd take the vector in by value, so the calling scope can `std::move` into it (or pass a temporary which will do this automatically), then `std::move` the constructor argument into the new member. That way you literally just have one vector the entire time.

```
class Holder {
public:
    Holder(vector<int> vref) : vec(std::move(vref)) {}
    vector<int> vec;
}

Holder* MakeHolder() {
    vector<int> v {1, 2};
    return new Holder(std::move(v));  // Or just `return new Holder({1,2});`
}

int main() {
    Holder *h = MakeHolder();
}
```

And, this way, if you want to keep the original vector alive (not moved-from) then that's fine too! Just pass it in and it'll get copied. Things will "just work" without really needing to know what's inside the constructor code (you only need to know that it takes a value).

The other thing I'd change is introducing `std::unique_ptr`, because you currently have a memory leak:

```
class Holder {
public:
    Holder(vector<int> vref) : vec(std::move(vref)) {}
    vector<int> vec;
}

std::unique_ptr<Holder> MakeHolder() {
    return std::make_unique<Holder>({1,2});
}

int main() {
    auto h = MakeHolder();
}
```

(Some people would spell `MakeHolder()`'s return type `auto`, but not me. I think it's important to know what you're going to get. For example, otherwise you have to read the code to know what the result's ownership semantics are! Is it a raw pointer? Something else?)

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to provide example with a memory leak

Comment: @Slava I only changed the pertinent elements, and the rest is the OP's code. But you're probably right that pointing this out is a good idea. Will add.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not clear on why my example had a memory leak. Unless you mean that the memory leaks when main() ends? Also, doesn't a copy have to be made at some point? Or would (in your suggested code where there is only one vector the whole time) the Holder object and the stack frame for the MakeHolder method simply both reference the same vector until the method completes?

Comment: @EricAtAIR: Yes that's what I mean - it's possible your "real" code doesn't have that flaw, but a smart pointer will help alleviate the risk anyway. And no there is no copy necessary: that is the beauty of move semantics. The original `v` is "moved from" - its data and state are stolen by the new version inside the `Holder`. This is not noticeable because the now-half-dead `v` immediately goes out of scope anyway, as `MakeHolder()` returns. A C++11 (or newer) book would be useful here.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the newly created object holding a reference to something that no longer exists?

No.  `Holder` stores the vector by value so it's vector and the function local one are different objects.

> Or is this just a more efficient way of copying the vector, in which case the fact that it was allocated on the stack makes no difference?

Yes.  if

```
Holder(vector<int>& vref) : vec(vref) {}
```

had been

```
Holder(vector<int> vref) : vec(vref) {}
```

Then you would first have to copy the vector into `vref` and then you would have to copy `vref` into `vec`.  By taking a reference you save that first copy.

---

Another way to do it would be

```
Holder(const vector<int>& vref) : vec(vref) {}
// or
Holder(vector<int> vref) : vec(std::move(vref)) {}
```

which allows you to accept lvalues and rvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Its member variable is a vector, not a reference, so it is a `Holder`'s own copy (and each `std::vector` privately owns its elements.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is the newly created object holding a reference to something that no longer exists?

No, copy constructor called for initialization of member variable `vec`

> Or is this just a more efficient way of copying the vector, in which case the fact that it was allocated on the stack makes no difference?

Yes, but common practice is to use `const` reference to avoid copy ctor on passing argument by value:

```
Holder(cont vector<int>& vref) : vec(vref) {}
```

so maybe somebody made a mistake and missed `const` or had some other reason not to use const reference here.

Note: with move semantics passing object by (const) reference in some cases could be even less efficient than passing by value.